# Append value to an input field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here i'm trying to append some text to an input field but everytime the old value gets replaced with new value.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="taginput" class="input" name="tags">
```

**Javascript**

```
function update(i){
 document.getElementById('taginput').value = i.innerHTML;
  }
```

no jquery please.

Comment: `document.getElementById('taginput').value += i.innerHTML;`

Comment: If you call update multiple times you're going to append all the html inside i again and again so it'll have many, many duplicates. Maybe that's what you want, but if not you may need to rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to get the old value first, and then add to it

```
function update(i){
    var elem = document.getElementById('taginput');
    var old  = elem.value;
    elem.value = old + i.innerHTML;
}
```

or you could add it to with `+=` directly

```
elem.value += i.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment).

```js
function update(i){
    let elem = document.getElementById('taginput');
    elem.value = elem.value + i.innerHtml; 
    // Or elem.value += i.innerHtml;
    // elem.value = elem.value.concat(i.innerHtml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value += ' doe';
alert(input.value);
```

```html
<input value="john" type="text">
```

`innerHTML` makes no sense as the `input`'s value.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="my_msg" type="text">
</body>
<script>
document.getElementById('my_msg').value = "text-value";
</script>
</html>
```

document.getElementById('my_msg').value = "text-value";

Use above script to append 'text-value' to input field.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. To give a good answer please write your code in a snippet and explain what your code does.